# Moving local json/text file to public folder while building with webpack

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack

I have two files sampleJson.json/sampleText.txt in the src folder (src -> data -> sampleJson.json/sampleText.txt).
I am going to copy these files in public while webpack is building app in both dev and prod mode. I am using ejected create-react-app react v16.6 and webpack 4.19. What should I change in webpack config to acheive this goal.

Comment: Why dont you just put those files in public as well before building it?

Comment: Because they are constantly changed and working in src folder in much faster than another folder. Also, all files are centralized in src folder and managing them is more convenient.